# Как добавить куки в запрос? WebView2

Tags: c#, winforms, webview

Как добавить в WebView 2 на основе WinForms кукисы?

Пробовал разные варианты, в интернете по сути нет информации как сделать

Вот последний вариант как пробовал. Просто чтобы хотя бы заработало без ошибок. В идеале есть список из 13 куков от сайта в формате NetScape , надо все загрузить и отправить на сайт и соответственно открыть сайт. Благодарю за помощь!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вставьте код текстом

Comment: Очевидно, у вас не инициализировано ядро `CoreWebView`. Выполните `await webView.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null)` перед тем как обращаться к браузеру впервые.

Comment: Не в комментари, не хостинг, а в сам пост, а комментарий удалите. Но я вам сказал уже, что сделать.

Comment: @aepot с этим я разобрался, но у меня много куки. Аж 14 строк. Их то каким образом добавить? Пробовал через System.Net Cookie , он добавляет только 1, CookieCollection не хочет, а через CoreWebView2 я так и не понял как добавить список куков. Подскажите пожалуйста. Спасибо!

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос, задайте его отдельно.